# Create new console buffer?

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a Battleship game that will use the command line for IO.

Currently the game is designed to be two-player, and I wanted to do something that would clear the screen after each turn to prevent each player from simply looking at the other player's board. Ideally, I'd like it to be something similar to how Emacs runs its games (i.e. it creates a separate buffer and displays it in the same window), especially since I don't want to completely clear the user's console.

Based on my limited research, I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but I figured I'd ask to confirm.

Note: I *really* do not want to create a GUI for this project, as the intention was for it to be something that I could run from the console. I just wanted to get that out of the way since several of the answers I saw recommended that.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no pure Java way of controlling the system console as completely as you need

Comment: That's sorta what I thought, but I was hoping there was a chance. Oh well. Thanks!